# Place components to the right of tabs in a JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing

OK I'm trying to modify an existing answer from below link to fit my needs.  In my case I need to set the JTabbedPane.TOP, but then the buttons disappear.

I'm not too familiar with Swing, so someone please let me know. Below is the full working code example from link.

[How to place components beneath tabs in right oriented JTabbedPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468522/how-to-place-components-beneath-tabs-in-right-oriented-jtabbedpane)

```
    public class RightTabPaneButtonPanel {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        new RightTabPaneButtonPanel().makeUI();
      }
    });
  }



    public void makeUI() {
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      JPanel tab = new JPanel();
      tab.setName("tab" + (i + 1));
      tab.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
      tabbedPane.add(tab);

      JButton button = new JButton("B" + (i + 1));
      button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
      panel.add(button);
    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(tabbedPane);
    frame.pack();
    Rectangle tabBounds = tabbedPane.getBoundsAt(0);

    Container glassPane = (Container) frame.getGlassPane();
    glassPane.setVisible(true);
    glassPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.weightx = 1.0;
    gbc.weighty = 1.0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    int margin = tabbedPane.getWidth() - (tabBounds.x + tabBounds.width);
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, margin);
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) tabBounds.getWidth() - margin,
            panel.getPreferredSize().height));
    glassPane.add(panel, gbc);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try printing out that Dimension object that you pass to `panel.setPreferredSize`.

Comment: Where do you want to have your button panel? NORTHEAST?

Comment: Yeah NORTHEAST.  Just right align the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.weightx = 1.0;
gbc.weighty = 1.0;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(panel.getPreferredSize().width,
            (int) tabBounds.getHeight()));
glassPane.add(panel, gbc);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach that uses the `OverlayLayout`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;

public class TabbedPaneWithComponent
{
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout( new OverlayLayout(panel) );

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.add("1", new JTextField("one"));
        tabbedPane.add("2", new JTextField("two"));
        tabbedPane.setAlignmentX(1.0f);
        tabbedPane.setAlignmentY(0.0f);

        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Check Me");
        checkBox.setOpaque( false );
        checkBox.setAlignmentX(1.0f);
        checkBox.setAlignmentY(0.0f);

        JPanel right = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 5, 0) );
        right.setOpaque( false );
        right.setAlignmentX(1.0f);
        right.setAlignmentY(0.0f);
        right.add( new JCheckBox("Check Me") );
        right.add( new JCheckBox("Or Check Me") );
        right.setMaximumSize( right.getPreferredSize() );


        panel.add( checkBox );
//      panel.add( right );
        panel.add(tabbedPane);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabbedPane With Component");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( panel );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setSize(400, 100);
        frame.setVisible( true );
        System.out.println(checkBox.getPreferredSize() + " : " + right.getPreferredSize());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good thanks.  I didn't event know you could use OverlayLayout.  I guess OverlayLayout is preferred over the getGlassPane solution?

Comment: A GlassPane affects the entire GUI. if you use the GlassPane for this functionality then you can't use it for anything else. A GlassPane is typically used for temporary processing. See the Swing tutorial example that uses a [Glass Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) to temporarily disable the frame. The OverlayLayout only affects the panel and its child components so I would suggest it is a better solution.